# What the issue: host not found: 3 (NXDOMAIN)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, dns

I registered the domain in the zone tk, but it doesn't work. My hosting - is Heroku.
My app it is work on Heroku address: http://mighty-oasis-6099.herokuapp.com/ 
May be IP-address is not work? (Are Heroku changed IP?)

PRIRODA-SITE.TK:

```
DOT.TK.DNS.Service
Type: A-record
Hostname: priroda-site.tk
IP address: 75.101.145.87

Type: A-record
Hostname: www.priroda-site.tk
IP address: 75.101.145.87


ark@ark-Aspire-5750G:~/appq$ heroku domains
=== mighty-oasis-6099 Domain Names
mighty-oasis-6099.herokuapp.com
priroda-site.tk
www.priroda-site.tk

ark@ark-Aspire-5750G:~/appq$ host www.priroda-site.tk
Host www.priroda-site.tk not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)
```

Comment: missing A record for www.priroda-site.tk. Also. missing A record for priroda-site.tk. no NS records in zone.

Comment: How to change, that it work? Help me!

Comment: by adding desired A records and needed NS records.

Comment: Types: A-record, CNAME, MX record. -> on the TK zone!

Comment: I have two A-records. Wirh www and without www. It is not work!

Comment: nameservers, authoritative for parent zone, reflect delegation to your authoritatives nameserver now (NS01.DOT.TK ... NS04.DOT.TK). A records can be queried from those, NS records are present too. It's probably caching of negatives now. Seems you weren't patient enough waiting for delegation to take place.

Comment: When NS record are work?

Comment: on authoritative servers? immediately. cached negatives? depends on SOA settings.